# Intersecting image within a div

Tags: html, css, image

So, I'm trying to place images within each of these skewed boxes which are divs by themselves.
https://i.gyazo.com/40b075146572cb239155ecbe8c782162.png

Currently, when I try to put pictures inside, they overlap like this: https://gyazo.com/8b7eb84bf60385d30661eed771323d9b

I had *assumed* that overflow:hidden; would accomplish this, but no dice.
Any thoughts?

```css
.wiki {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  font-family: 'Gentium Basic', serif;
  color: var(--cBlack);
  padding: 0.8em;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 170px;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 5em;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-15deg);
  transform: skewY(-15deg);
}

.wiki header {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(15deg);
  transform: skewY(15deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

.wiki img {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(15deg);
  transform: skewY(15deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 445px;
  bottom: 115px;
  right: 12px;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wiki">
  <section>
    <header class="col-head">WIKI</header>
    <figure><img src="https://placehold.it/800x800" alt="Wiki image" class="cover"></figure>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `overflow: hidden` on the skewed element (`.wiki`) rather than the `img`

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.wiki {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  font-family: 'Gentium Basic', serif;
  color: var(--cBlack);
  padding: 0.8em;
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 170px;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 5em;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-15deg);
  transform: skewY(-15deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wiki header {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(15deg);
  transform: skewY(15deg);
  z-index: 2;
}

.wiki img {
  -webkit-transform: skewY(15deg);
  transform: skewY(15deg);
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  height: 445px;
  bottom: 115px;
  right: 12px;
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wiki">
  <section>
    <header class="col-head">WIKI</header>
    <figure><img src="https://lorempixel.com/800/800/" alt="Wiki image" class="cover"></figure>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Doh! Yes, of course! Damnit. Should've been obvious. Appreciate it. haha!